# WaWorkerHost.exe crashes role: CallbackException

Tags: c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, azure, azure-worker-roles, load-generator

When I run my WorkerRole C# application on Azure, after a while waworkerhost.exe crashes due the following exception:

```
Application: WaWorkerHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.CallbackException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

I have an application that generates load to a webserver. I don't care about the actual response, but i want to control the number of requests made per second.
Therefore i have a Timer that fires every second and generates a number of requests. I have tried the following options:

- Parallel.For with WebRequests
- For loop with ASync WebRequests
- For loop with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(do
  webrequest)

When the number of requests increase, the exception occurs (8+ req/sec). The same exception for all three options. When I run the role in local DevelopmentFabric all three options work just fine. If someone could give me some pointers on what might be going wrong I appreciate it. If you have other ideas to generate this type of load from Azure and C#, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Would be helpful see the code you are using.

Comment: Turn out to be an IntelliTrace issue, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/543da280-2e5c-4e1a-b416-9999c7a9b841

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and tag it as such?

Answer (score 1):

The author answered the question in the comment to the original post, but for better visibility, I'm reporting it to here:

> Turn out to be an IntelliTrace issue, see
>   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/543da280-2e5c-4e1a-b416-9999c7a9b841:
>
> ...
>
> After redeploying my solution with Intellitrace disabled, the issues
>   where resolved, and my WorkerRole stayed healthy.